# How to use the setLabels method for forwardingrule?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, rest, forwarding

I can't add a label to a ForwardingRule from the Google Cloud Platform console (GUI).
However, the API reference states that you can add a label to the forwarding rule with the setLabels method.
What is the setLabels method?
And how to use the setLabels method?

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/forwardingRules/setLabels

Comment: I modified your link was wrongly pointing to Forwarding Rules List instead of setLabels, to learn more about this check [Labeling resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources)

Comment: compute engine has a setlabel api (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/setLabels)

Comment: thanks Pedro , i found it.

Answer (score 1):

i found it

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/forwardingRules/setLabels

I was looking for an API doc, but it was in another location.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/apis

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Method:instances.setLabels](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/forwardingRules/setLabels). This method will allow to set labels on an instance.

Compute Engine Forwarding Rules can be [added or updated](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/forwarding-rules/update) as the example below:

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules update example-fr --region=us-central1 --update-labels=k0=value1,k1=value2 --remove-labels=k3
```

To learn more about Labels check [Labeling Resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources).